# Why does the filesystem not recognize a file named ../blah.sh

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, ls, ext4

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with ext4 filesystem.

When I make a file like:

```
touch ../blah.sh
```

It does not show up when I use:

```
ls -al
```

When I try to delete the file with:

```
rm * --> : rm: cannot remove '*': No such file or directory.
```

However when I delete it with:

```
rm ../blah.sh ---> it succeeds.
```

Besides this I am able to edit the file with vim, put code in there and then run it like:

```
./../blah.sh
```

How is this behavior possible? Is this bash specific behaviour or from the operating system?  and is it possible to hide a file like this?

Comment: You'd need to do `ls -al ..` or `ls -l ../blah.sh` to see files in the parent directory.  `ls -al` just looks in the current directory, `.`.  This applies to any type of Unix file system.  If you're really into esoterica, if your current directory is `/` (the root file system) and you try the operations, you will see `blah.sh` because the parent of the root directory is the root directory.  OTOH, you shouldn't be messing around in the root directory, especially not with write privileges (as super-user).  There's far too much danger of you making a mistake, especially if you ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you use .. you are creating the file in the parent directory of where you currently are.

If you try this it should show the file:

```
ls -al ..
```

Also for rm you'd have to do the following, though it's dangerous obviously.

```
rm ../*
```

Comment: I suggest that you should suggest `rm ../blah.sh` to avoid the danger.'